# Custom code help for a likert scale report

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I’m trying to do something a little complicated for Webflow. I’m stuck on how to tackle this problem and I’m wondering if anyone can help. Basically, I’m trying to create a table graph that shows a user the results of a likert scale graph.

I got some code that works well to make it show up like this:
[dashboard with one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OsO1.png)

```
<style>
  .tf-bg-color {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .tf-bg-no-color {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
  }
</style>

<!-- Add this HTML code to your page for each element you want to show/hide -->
<div id="q1a" class="tf-bg-color">1</div>
<div id="q1a-no-color" class="tf-bg-no-color">1</div>
<div id="q1b" class="tf-bg-color">2</div>
<div id="q1b-no-color" class="tf-bg-no-color">2</div>
<div id="q1c" class="tf-bg-color">3</div>
<div id="q1c-no-color" class="tf-bg-no-color">3</div>
<div id="q1d" class="tf-bg-color">4</div>
<div id="q1d-no-color" class="tf-bg-no-color">4</div>
<div id="q1e" class="tf-bg-color">5</div>
<div id="q1e-no-color" class="tf-bg-no-color">5</div>

<!-- Add this JavaScript code to the end of your <body> section -->
<script>
  const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tf-bg-color');

  function showElement(element) {
    element.style.display = 'inline-flex';
  }

  function hideElement(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function toggleElement(element, value) {
    if (element.innerText === value.toString()) {
      showElement(element);
    } else {
      hideElement(element);
    }
  }

  const variable = 1; // Replace with your variable

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const id = elements[i].id;
    toggleElement(elements[i], variable);

    if (id) {
      const noColorElement = document.querySelector(`#${id}-no-color`);
      if (noColorElement) {
        if (elements[i].style.display === 'none') {
          showElement(noColorElement);
        } else {
          hideElement(noColorElement);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The problem I have is that when I add multiple rows I can't figure out how to work out the javascript so that I can get the circles to show up behind the different questions.

Here's what I have so far but it isn't working. Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?

[Dashboard with code that doesn't work and two rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oJpM.png)

```
<!-- Add this CSS code to your <head> section -->
.tf-bg-color {
display: none;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #b7adac; /* replace with the color you want /
color: #FFFFFF; / replace with the text color you want /
font-size: 24px; / replace with the font size you want /
font-weight: bold; / replace with the font weight you want */
}

.tf-bg-color-q2 {
display: none;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: #b7adac; /* replace with the color you want /
color: #FFFFFF; / replace with the text color you want /
font-size: 24px; / replace with the font size you want /
font-weight: bold; / replace with the font weight you want */
}

.tf-bg-no-color {
display: none;
color: #000000;
font-size: 14px;
}
</style>

<!-- Add this HTML code to your page for each element you want to show/hide -->
<div id="q1a" class="tf-bg-color">1</div>
<div id="q1b" class="tf-bg-color">2</div>
<div id="q1c" class="tf-bg-color">3</div>
<div id="q1d" class="tf-bg-color">4</div>
<div id="q1e" class="tf-bg-color">5</div>
<div id="q2a" class="tf-bg-color-q2">1</div>
<div id="q2b" class="tf-bg-color-q2">2</div>
<div id="q2c" class="tf-bg-color-q2">3</div>
<div id="q2d" class="tf-bg-color-q2">4</div>
<div id="q2e" class="tf-bg-color-q2">5</div>
<!-- Add this JavaScript code to the end of your <body> section -->
<!-- Add this JavaScript code to the end of your <body> section -->
<script>
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tf-bg-color, .tf-bg-color-q2');

  function showElement(element) {
    element.style.display = 'inline-flex';
  }

  function hideElement(element) {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }

  function toggleElement(element, value, className) {
    if (element.innerText === value.toString() && element.classList.contains(className)) {
      showElement(element);
    } else {
      hideElement(element);
    }
  }

  const variable = 1; // Replace with your variable
  const variable2 = 2; // Replace with your second variable

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const id = elements[i].id;

    toggleElement(elements[i], variable, 'tf-bg-color');
    toggleElement(elements[i], variable2, 'tf-bg-color-q2');

  for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    const id = elements[i].id;
    toggleElement(elements[i], variable);

    if (id) {
      const noColorElement = document.querySelector(`#${id}-no-color`);
      if (noColorElement) {
        if (elements[i].style.display === 'none') {
          showElement(noColorElement);
        } else {
          hideElement(noColorElement);
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be vastly simplified with a pure CSS solution.  If I understood correctly, you want to be able to add a background-color to the selected option in the scale for a report.   A good way to do that is with a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).  You can manually set this value in your HTML or do it using JavaScript.  Here's the gist of how you could use it style your report:

Assuming your markup looked like this for the scale:

```html
<ol class="scale" data-value="4">
  <li class="choice">
    <span class="score">1</span>
    <span class="label">Strongly Disagree</span>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <span class="score">2</span>
    <span class="label">Disagree</span>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <span class="score">3</span>
    <span class="label">Neutral</span>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <span class="score">4</span>
    <span class="label">Agree</span>
  </li>
  <li class="choice">
    <span class="score">5</span>
    <span class="label">Strongly Agree</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Then in your CSS you'd have the following:

```css
[data-value="1"] .choice:nth-child(1) .score,
[data-value="2"] .choice:nth-child(2) .score,
[data-value="3"] .choice:nth-child(3) .score,
[data-value="4"] .choice:nth-child(4) .score,
[data-value="5"] .choice:nth-child(5) .score {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

So, by simply changing the `data-value` the appropriate choice would be highlighted.

Here's a more complete demo:

```css
.scale {
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.choice {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.score {
  align-items: center;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 2rem;
}

[data-value="1"] .choice:nth-child(1) .score,
[data-value="2"] .choice:nth-child(2) .score,
[data-value="3"] .choice:nth-child(3) .score,
[data-value="4"] .choice:nth-child(4) .score,
[data-value="5"] .choice:nth-child(5) .score {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.label {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #aaa;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 20em) {
  .scale {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  }

  .choice {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/*  for the demo */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap");

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

main {
  padding: 1rem;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.title {
  margin: 0;
}

.subtitle {
  color: #aaa;
  margin: 0;
}

.sectionHeader {
  padding: 1rem 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.statement {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.group {
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <header class="sectionHeader">
      <h2 class="title">Competence Answers</h2>
      <p class="subtitle">These answers are average</p>
    </header>
    <div role="group" class="group">
      <p class="statement">My work with this team contributes to my individual development as a professional.</p>
      <ol class="scale" data-value="4">
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">1</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">2</span>
          <span class="label">Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">3</span>
          <span class="label">Neutral</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">4</span>
          <span class="label">Agree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">5</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Agree</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div role="group" class="group">
      <p class="statement">The majority of my teammates look for better ways to improve their capabilities and skills, so we all benefit collectively.</p>
      <ol class="scale" data-value="3">
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">1</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">2</span>
          <span class="label">Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">3</span>
          <span class="label">Neutral</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">4</span>
          <span class="label">Agree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">5</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Agree</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div role="group" class="group">
      <p class="statement">The organization provides me with opportunities to develop new skills.</p>
      <ol class="scale" data-value="5">
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">1</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">2</span>
          <span class="label">Disagree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">3</span>
          <span class="label">Neutral</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">4</span>
          <span class="label">Agree</span>
        </li>
        <li class="choice">
          <span class="score">5</span>
          <span class="label">Strongly Agree</span>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```